# How to set function arguments to execute different set of m-files?

Tags: matlab, calling-convention

I am using Matlab.

I have a main function `main.m`. And I have two sets of m-files, named:

```
Set A = {Area_triangle.m, Perimeter_triangle.m}
Set B = {Area_square.m, Perimeter_square.m}
```

Is there any methods such that it can achieve `main(triangle)` can execute m-files in set A while `main(square)` can execute m-files in set B?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a Matlab-script stored in an m-file, you can use `run`. With a switch-statement, it's easy to determine which set should be used. Then we can iterate over all the files in the given set and execute the scripts.

The following function can be called with `main('triangle')` and `main('square')`:

```
function main(shape)

A = {'Area_triangle.m', 'Perimeter_triangle.m'};
B = {'Area_square.m', 'Perimeter_square.m'};

switch shape
    case 'triangle'
        S = A;
    case 'square'
        S = B;
    otherwise
        error('Shape not defined!');
end

for i = 1:length(S)
    run(S{i})
end
```