# Matlab: reference to functions in a set of m-files

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a directory with n m-files (cI_0001.m, cI_0002.m, ...) defining each a complex function that should be used for image transformation with imtransform the kind of:

```
conformal = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], @cI_0001, []);
T = imtransform(C, conformal, ...);
```

In the simplest case I want a loop that apply imtransform to an image C for all the given functions. So I made a cell array for the directory with the m-file names without extension (m_name_list) and I think I need a kind of a pointer in maketform() to the elements in m_name_list. How can this be correctly formulated?

```
for i=1:n
   conformal = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], @pointer_to_the_ith_element_in_m_name_list, []);
   T = imtransform(C, conformal, ...);
   imwrite(T, ...);
end
```

I saw the proposal with run in [How to set function arguments to execute different set of m-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648737/how-to-set-function-arguments-to-execute-different-set-of-m-files) but this seems not working with the function calling in maketform().

EDIT: I include a list with function names + extension to which pointers could be made (possible extended to a list of paths+names):

```
m_dir_entries = dir(strcat(CM_inverse_folder_path, '*.m'));
m_name_list   = cell(1,length(m_dir_entries));
for k=1:length(m_dir_entries)
  m_name_list{k} = m_dir_entries(k).name; 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str2func`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) to create a function handle to each of the .m files

```
% Add the folder to your path
addpath(CM_inverse_folder_path)

function_list = {'cI_0001.m', 'cI_0002.m'};

% Remove the extensions
[~, function_list] = cellfun(@fileparts, function_list, 'UniformOutput', false);

for k = 1:n
    func = str2func(function_list{k});
    conformal = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], func, []);
    T = imtransform(C, conformal, ...);
    imwrite(T, ...);
end

% Remove the folder from the path
rmpath(CM_inverse_folder_path)
```

Comment: Should the elements in function_list be names+extensions or paths+names+ext. because the m-files are on an other disk? If I am using names+ext. I got: Error in tformarray (line 233)
M = tforminv(G,T);
Error in imtransform (line 276)
B = tformarray(args.A, args.tform, args.resampler, tdims_a, tdims_b, ...
Error in conformalInverse_Management_Test (line 93)
        T = imtransform(C, conformal, 'bicubic', 'UData', uData,'VData', vData, 'XData', xData,'YData', yData, 'Size', [cm_out_h cm_out_w], 'FillValues', FillValues_color)

Comment: @GünterBachelier Sorry, you probably need to *not* use the extensions. I've shown the modified code above.

Comment: the combination of addpath(CM_inverse_folder_path); and function names without extension worked! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @GünterBachelier Consider accepting answers in all the questions you have posted.