# Matlab: func2str from a function in a m-file

Tags: matlab

In a main m-file I have

```
conformal = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], @conformalInverse_0001, []);
```

used in imtransform that refers to the function defined in conformalInverse_0001.m:

```
function U = conformalInverse_0001(X, ~)
%#codegen
U = [zeros(size(X))];
Z = complex(X(:,1),X(:,2));
W = 1./(4.*Z.^2-1);
U(:,2) = imag(W);
U(:,1) = real(W);
```

How can I get the string '1./(4.*Z.^2-1)' in the main program?

Comment: You can't unless your function returns the string.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to read in conformalInverse_0001.m and parse it to extract a particular line? I assume conformalInverse_0001.m is your own function? And why do you want that line as a string rather than as a function?

Comment: @horchler: I want to process the sting and use it as part of folder and file names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186812/matlab-reference-to-functions-in-a-set-of-m-files

Comment: If there is really no way to get the function string from the m-file I had to use textscan to read the file, extract the "W = ..." line and the corresponding string.

Comment: @GünterBachelier I also thought about that kind of solution... took me a while to make an answer (not so elegant). How can I search for "W = " using `textscan`? Searching for a regular expression confuses me.

Comment: @Rotem: I used strcmp to compare the first four characters with 'W = ' see my improvised answer below. Would be easer with a Perl-like syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hacked two solutions with textscan: first knowing the line number and second searching the line that starts with substring 'W = '

```
% read line line_num = 5 and process string 
f_id = fopen(conformalInverse_m_path);
conformalInverse_cell = textscan(f_id,'%s','delimiter','\n');               %disp(conformalInverse_cell); % {68×1 cell}
func_string = conformalInverse_cell{1}{line_num};                           disp(func_string); % W = 1./(4.*Z.^2-1); OK 
func_string_2=func_string(5:end-1);                                         disp(func_string_2); % 1./(4.*Z.^2-1); OK 


% read first line that starts with substring 'W = ' and process string 
W_string = 'W = '; 
for i=1:100
    func_string = conformalInverse_cell{1}{i};
    Firt4=func_string(1:4);                                                 %disp(['i = ', num2str(i), ': First4 = ', Firt4]);
    if strcmp(Firt4,W_string) == 1; line_nr = i; break;  end; 
end
func_string_2 = conformalInverse_cell{1}{line_nr};                          
func_string_3=func_string_2(5:end-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it, but it's not so elegant...

Assume `conformalInverse_0001.m` is a file in your folder.

You can parse the file as a text file, and search for your formula.

Example:
Assume you know the location is 5'th line in file, and start with `W =`.
You can use something like the following code to read `'1./(4.*Z.^2-1)'` in the main program:

```
%Open file for reading.
fid = fopen('conformalInverse_0001.m', 'r');

%Read 5 lines.
s = textscan(fid, '%s', 5, 'delimiter', '\n');    
fclose(fid);

%Get the 5'th line.
s = s{1}(5);

%Convert cell array to string.
s = s{1};

%Get characters from the 5'th character to one char before end of string.
s = s(5:end-1)
```

Result: `s = 1./(4.*Z.^2-1)`

You can check [textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) documentation for finding more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem here, but what about adding into your `conformalInverse_0001` function something like:

```
str = '1./(4.*Z.^2-1)';
save('temp_str','str') % or whatever data that you want to save from it
```

and then adding in your main file:

```
load('str.mat')% or you can use 'impordata'
```

where you want to extract it.